# Get Google search results in c#

Tags: c#, .net, html, browser

I'm trying to get google search results using HTML Agility Pack, but I am not getting the correct page.  The page I am getting is Google's main page,

This is the link the C#'s WebBrowser gives me : 
https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=hello+world&pbx=1&oq=hello+world&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=14782l16242l0l16965l11l7l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5586f0ad4776d5b3&biw=268&bih=250

(if you try to paste it to a normal browser it will change to the URL below)

This is if I use  a regular browser: 
https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=hello+world&pbx=1&oq=hello+world&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=14782l16242l0l16965l11l7l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&biw=268&bih=250&cad=h

```
private void GotoGoogleButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
}

private void getResultsButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    url = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
    start_parsing(url);
}

public void start_parsing(string URL_) 
{
    //This function is used to Parse Html source using Html Agility Pack into nodes, and take the important ones (mainly : a,form,iframe)

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = webGet.Load(URL_);
    var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

    // ...

    // Continue with parsing...
}
```

How do I get the search results instead of the home page?

Comment: You have to format your code (in both your posts and in your editor).  People can't read it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better served to look into [Google's RESTful API for search](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html)

It appears you can get an Atom feed containing search results.

Comment: yes, you can hack a screen scraper together but that will lead to nothing but trouble in the end. using the api is the best way to reliably solve the problem you face

Answer (score 2):

simply you can replace `#` with `search?`. but why cant you use [google search api](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) for this

Comment: I replaced them # and search? but they're not the only difference between the 2 links

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the .NET wrapper around the Google Custom Search API

http://code.google.com/p/cse-net/